Test Vue3 project with safetest
I have a Vue project.
I have to test it with safetest.
I followed https://azukiazusa.dev/blog/safetest-a-test-library-offering-a-new-ui-testing-approach/ and readme of https://github.com/kolodny/safetest/.
But I can not run the test code.
There is error -

Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content
contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue
files.
How to solve it?

Ofcourse, I've installed @vitejs/plugin-vue module.
I try 'npm run safetest', there is error 'Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.'

How did you configure it for Vue? The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's not enough to link an article and say you did the same thing, especially since it's not in English. You're likely supposed to use this https://github.com/kolodny/safetest/tree/main/examples/vite-vue-ts as a starting point

I followed setting of github.com/kolodny/safetest/tree/main/examples/vite-vue-ts.

Please, provide a way to reproduce

What additional information do you need for reproducing?

A repo would be good. Codesandbox can be used for vite setups, but one may need to jump through hoops to make it work
